# Selecting a Capture Device Using the System Device Enumerator

Tags: c++, windows, qt5

I was tring to use this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377566%28v=VS.85%29.aspx, to select a capturing device.

Works perfectly on Visual Studio, but throws the following error QT:

```
 test.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in main.obj
  test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoCreateInstance@20   referenced in function "long __cdecl EnumerateDevices(struct _GUID const &,struct IEnumMoniker * *)" (?EnumerateDevices@@YAJABU_GUID@@PAPAUIEnumMoniker@@@Z)
  test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__VariantClear@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl DisplayDeviceInformation(struct IEnumMoniker *)" (?DisplayDeviceInformation@@YAXPAUIEnumMoniker@@@Z)
  test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__VariantInit@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl DisplayDeviceInformation(struct IEnumMoniker *)" (?DisplayDeviceInformation@@YAXPAUIEnumMoniker@@@Z)
 test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoUninitialize@0 referenced in function _main
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CoInitializeEx@8 referenced in function _main
```

I'm using windows 7 & QT 5.0.2.

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: The MSDN link above works on Visual Studio, but throws the following error on QT

Comment: In the first comment of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407292(v=vs.85).aspx

It is specified that the application needs to link with strmiids.lib, is that your case for the QT version ?

Comment: I have linked the lib "#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids")".

Comment: Does your QT code links against ole32.lib ?

Comment: No it doesn't, i'll try linking the ole32.lib now.

Comment: Adding ole32.lib and OleAut32.lib, solved the issue. Thanks for the help  @ woodleg.as :), Also if you can add the comment as an answer, i'll accept it and upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for "cocreateinstance unresolved external" on google and using the first link returned:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/5fc032e1-86d8-43c7-870b-f10599000605/

I spotted the third comment that indicates to link against ***"ole32.lib"***.

Your reply to my comment above indicates that ***"oleAut32.lib"*** is also required.

Also make sure to link against ***"strmiids.lib"***.

To sum up, required libraries are:

- ole32.lib
- oleaut32.lib
- strmiids.lib

Comment: A year and a half later, this page is the first link on Google :)